# WiFi stopped working after Ubuntu 16.04 updates

Tags: 16.04, wireless, updates

The WiFi connection on my HP Stream11 has stopped working since I installed the updates that I received this morning. How do I undo the update or get the wifi working again?

Comment: is `network-manager` running? you can see it by typing `sudo service network-manager status`

Comment: Yes - the response is active (running) since Mon 2018-07-23 10.14 ..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you miss to update wireless driver.

Run these two commands for wifi to work in Ubuntu.

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: What makes you think this will work? Does the OP have a card supported by this driver? I assume you are suggesting they download and install a driver, right? Why this one?

Comment: @terdon The OP already commented in a previous answer to this question which was unfortunately deleted by the owner due to undeserved downvoting as follows: *I am using the internal wifi but the code suggested has fixed the problem. I do not understand why the update stopped the wifi working but all is fine now.* I know the cause of the downvoting of the deleted answer, but this is not an appropriate topic for public consumption, so if you want to know this story you can private mod PM me.

Comment: @karel I would like to know more how did this answer helped OP . I assume OP miss to update wireless driver that's why I suggest this answer since it helped me too.

Comment: @JohnJoe The OP (**O**wner of the **P**ost) is the person who asked the above question. He posted the following comment below your deleted other answer: *I am using the internal wifi but the code suggested has fixed the problem. I do not understand why the update stopped the wifi working but all is fine now.*

Comment: @karel Yes, I know, but people here want me to explain how did the suggested code solved OP's issue. Otherwise they keep downvoting my answer.

Comment: I can't provide an answer to that question without having access to one of two things. 1. I have a device with a similar problem and the code also worked on my device. or 2. I have the same device as the OP or physical access to the OP's device. Otherwise I get information about whether an answer worked or not by looking at the voting on that answer, the same as everyone else does.